# How to iterate this stdClass in PHP

Tags: php, loops, stdclass

Can you help to iterate this stdClass with a loop? I want to print just the values.

```
stdClass Object ( [GetInfoResult] => stdClass Object ( [string] => Array ( [0] => My Value 1 [1] => My Value 2 [2] => My Value 3 [3] => My Value 4 [4] => My val 5 [5] => My val 6 [6] => My last val ) ) )
```

Example:

- My Value 1
- My Value 2
- My Value 3
- ... etc

Comment: @mulquin I saw this page before but I can't iterate correctly. I don't know what is the problem.

Comment: could you please post any code you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

The values you want to print are in an array that's nested in the object. Just access the array and use `foreach`.

```
foreach ($object->GetInfoResult->string as $string) {
    echo $string;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes I can print it correctly now.